# Locale Switcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I am busy going through **PBP - Agile Web Development with Rails** and implementing the locale switcher.

However when I try switch between english and spanish I get a error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/en"
```

My controller is as follows:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize

  def index
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to store_path(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
      @products = Product.order(:title)
      @cart = current_cart
    end
  end
end
```

and an extract of the application.hmtl.erb that is being used;

```
<div id="banner">
  <%= form_tag store_path, class: 'locale' do %>
    <%= select_tag 'set_locale', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s), onchange: 'this.form.submit()' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
    <%= javascript_tag "$('.locale input').hide()" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
  <%= @page_title || t('.title') %>
</div>
```

the routing folder is as follows:

```
scope'(:locale)' do
  resources :users
  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  resources :products do
    get :who_bought, on: :member
  end
root to: 'store#index', as: 'store'
end
```

Cant figure out what I did wrong. If I enter /en or /es in the url it works correctly. However choosing it in the drop down that is created I get the error mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, the form_tag was expecting a POST so I changed

```
<%= form_tag store_path, class: 'locale' do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag store_path, class: 'locale', :method => :get do %>
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an slash in the scope as guides states:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :books
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Comment: Using the bracket just doesn't force the use of a locale in your routes, tried it anyway and still getting the same issue. Think it has something to do with the submit trying to post rather than calling as a GET but that is just a guess